# Powerdns GeoIP Unable to load module '/usr/lib64/pdns/libgeoipbackend.so':

Tags: domain-name-system, powerdns, centos8

I am trying to activate geoip module on powerdns I am getting strange error message. GeoIP db installed

Package GeoIP-1.6.12-7.el8.x86_64 is already installed.
Centos 8
nginx

/etc/pdns/pdns.conf

```
launch=gmysql
gmysql-host=localhost
gmysql-user=myuser
gmysql-password=mysqlpsw
gmysql-dbname=powerdns-db

launch+=geoip
geoip-database-files=/home/tiramus/www/geoip2/GeoLite2-City.mmdb
geoip-zones-file=/etc/pdns/geo.yml
geoip-database-cache=memory
```

version

```
[root@srv2-gb usr]# pdns_control version
4.3.0
```

Unable to load module '/usr/lib64/pdns/libgeoipbackend.so': /usr/lib64/pdns/libgeoipbackend.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

(edit) Backend yum added

```
================================================================================
 Package                      Arch        Version          Repository      Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 pdns-backend-ldap            x86_64      4.3.0-5.el8      epel           100 k
 pdns-backend-lua2            x86_64      4.3.0-5.el8      epel           115 k
 pdns-backend-pipe            x86_64      4.3.0-5.el8      epel            65 k
 pdns-backend-postgresql      x86_64      4.3.0-5.el8      epel            58 k
 pdns-backend-remote          x86_64      4.3.0-5.el8      epel           177 k
 pdns-backend-sqlite          x86_64      4.3.0-5.el8      epel            46 k
 pdns-backend-tinydns         x86_64      4.3.0-5.el8      epel            69 k
Installing dependencies:
 tinycdb                      x86_64      0.78-9.el8       AppStream       35 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  8 Packages
```

no geo

Comment: How did you install powerdns? Do you have the powerdns geoip backend itself installed?

Comment: I installed by command yum -y install pdns pdns-backend-mysql.x86_64 php-mcrypt pdns-recursor pdns-tools yaml-cpp-devel

Comment: geoip backend in centos 8 removed after version of 4.2 there is no way to install.

Comment: uninstall centos/epel packages and installing from upstream repo may be helpful? https://repo.powerdns.com/

Comment: you're right powerdns repo has geoip backend module where others not thank you very much if you can make it I will tick as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [PowerDNS packages in the EPEL for Centos 8](https://centos.pkgs.org/8/epel-x86_64/pdns-4.3.0-5.el8.x86_64.rpm.html) repository do not appear to include a package for the GeoIP backend.

The [upstream PowerDNS repo](https://repo.powerdns.com/) for Centos 8 does have a `pdns-backend-geoip` package, though.

Uninstalling the EPEL PowerDNS packages and instead installing PowerDNS Authoritative from the upstream repo (including the `pdns-backend-geoip` package) should help.